Ubuntu Server and Vm's
I have Ubuntu Server questions.
When I install Ubuntu Server on my Rack Server if I want to run many vm's I then have to install install Multipass on the Rack Server?
And once installed I can install normal Ubuntu in a vm and then I can install various versions of Windows in vms as well?
Am I correct in all that?
Thanks
Valshar

Thanks for the added info and help.
Since I need to run 5-6 Windows vm's I will do reading on qemu-kvm to see if it can meet my needs.

Thanks you very much for the further info and help, I really appreciate it.

Hey, I would do that but I only see 2 things beside your answers a grey flag on left of answer and grey pencil on the right.
I thought maybe add block or virus was keeping it hidden so I disabled it all and still not grey check mark anywhere on screen.

I have converted my comments to an answer. Now you can accept it using the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅.

Multipass
Multipass is for Ubuntu server guests only. Multipass doesn't have Ubuntu desktop installed by default. But you may install the Ubuntu-Desktop in the Multipass Ubuntu server, and connect to it remotely using xrdp.
QEMU-KVM
You may want to install qemu-kvm if you want to install Windows as a guest.
Step 1: Check if your server is compatible with KVM
Open a terminal in your Ubuntu server and run the command:
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo

If the command returns a value of 0, your processor is not capable of running KVM. On the other hand, any other number means you can proceed with the installation.
Next, check if your system can use KVM acceleration:
sudo kvm-ok

It should output:
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used

Step 2: Install KVM Packages
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils

Step 3: Authorize Users (may not be necessary)
Only members of the libvirt and kvm user groups can run virtual machines. If you want specific users to run VMs, add them to those user groups.
sudo adduser [username] libvirt
sudo adduser [username] kvm

Replace [username] with the actual username.
Source of the above how to install KVM.
Step 4: Install VMM on (another) Ubuntu with Desktop
Since your Ubuntu server installed on the rack server won't have a desktop GUI, you won't be able to use Virtual Machine Manager (VMM) directly on Ubuntu server host.
However, you may install the VMM GUI app in another Ubuntu Desktop and connect it to the server through an ssh+qemu tunnel.
Once you install VMM on your Ubuntu desktop, you can open the VMM app and go to File > Add Connections... menu. It will open a new window:


Check the box next to Connect to remote host over SSH.
Replace username if it is not root.
Under Hostname: add the IP address or the fully qualified domain
name (FQDN) of your Ubuntu server on the rack.
Then click connect.

Once connected, you may use the VMM GUI to create, manage, and connect to the Ubuntu, Windows and other VM guests.
You may create Ubuntu Desktop or server VMs using the VMM. Or if you have already created Ubuntu server VMs using Mulitipass, see Ubuntu multipass - VMM for how to use VMM to manage the VMs created via Multipass.
Hope this helps
